# Assign value based on index from another array numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a indices array like this:

```
idx = np.array([3,4,1], [0,0,0], [1,4,1], [2,0,2]]
```

And an array of zeros `A` with shape `4x5`

I would like to make all the indices in `idx` of `A` to be 1

For the above example, the final array should be:

```
[[0,1,0,1,1],  # values at index 3,4,1 are 1
 [1,0,0,0,0],  # value at index 0 is 1
 [0,1,0,0,1],  # values at index 1,4 are 1
 [1,0,1,0,0]]  # values at index 0,2 are 1
```

How can this be done in numpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use fancy indexing:

```
A = np.zeros((4, 5), dtype=int)

A[np.arange(len(idx))[:,None], idx] = 1
```

Or [`numpy.put_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.put_along_axis.html#numpy.put_along_axis):

```
A = np.zeros((4, 5), dtype=int)

np.put_along_axis(A, idx, 1, axis=1)
```

updated `A`:

```
array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
```